# main method not called in Play 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I have this main method:

```
object init extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger(classOf[MonitorLoad]).info("main()")
    val monitorActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MonitorLoad], name = "monitorLoad")
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 2 seconds, monitorActor, Tick)
    Logger(classOf[MonitorLoad]).info("Done setting up actor")
  }
}
```

(It sits in the `Application.scala` file in the basic app created with `play new`)

I see that this code is never called - my logs aren't printed, and the debugger won't stop there. Why is that? What is the correct way to run code at the start of a Play 2.1 app?

Comment: Check the Global object documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal

Comment: You were told by nico and me about Global object... use it pls!

Comment: @biesior - I am now, thanks! This question is not a dup btw.

Comment: But it can be considered as 'related' :) anyway glad, that you solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java Play 2.0 apps you can put a Global.java file in the 'app' directory:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings 
{
    public void onStart(Application app) 
    {
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```